# How can I get a window's icon name in Xorg?

Tags: python, xlib, clutter, xcb, wnck

I am attempting to get a window's icon *name* with python, for use in a pyclutter-based taskbar. I have gotten the XID via wnck, but wnck seems to only be capable of giving me a gtk.gdk.Pixbuf, which is not useful for clutter. I am sure there is *some* way to do this with python-xlib or python-xcb, I just can't find it :-)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe that icons have names, sorry to say.  Perhaps you want the window name?  Process name?

Comment: No? Am I wrong, or do you usually load it from a theme name such as 'firefox'? Or even if it is a file path, I could use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a gdk.Pixbuf to get the icon data and assign it to a clutter.Texture - the C version is:

```
clutter_texture_set_from_rgb_data (texture,
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf),
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha (pixbuf),
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf),
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_height (pixbuf),
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf),
                                   gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha (pixbuf) ? 4 : 3,
                                   CLUTTER_TEXTURE_NONE,
                                   &error);
```

but I'm pretty sure you can achieve the same in Python as well.